# ¿Ver la salida de console.error en Cordova?

Tags: android, angularjs-2.0, cordova

Estoy programando una aplicación en angular2 para cordova, cuando la ejecuto en el emulador del navegador funciona sin problemas:

```
> cordova run browser
```

El problema ocurre cuando la empaqueto en un apk e instalo en android:

```
> cordova run android
```

la aplicación se congela en la carga de la misma, me seria de mucha utilidad ver las salidas del `console.error` en el emulador ya sea por Android Studio u otra herramienta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para escuchar la salida de console.error se utiliza el ADB, una herramienta de línea de comandos que se instala como parte del SDK de Android.

El ADB se instala por defecto acá:

%AppData%\Local\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe

Y un comando básico para escuchar la salida del celular (con el equipo conectado por USB) sería:

```
adb logcat
```

ADB de permite filtrar los mensajes por paquete:

```
adb logcat com.tuempresa.tuapp:I *:S
```